# Should the super class know about sub classes

Tags: software-design

I am looking for the answer to this question:
Should the super class know about sub classes?

Example:

```
abstract class A {
 add(B) // Here is my problem. I am not really sure but is it correct the super class
 // knows about "B" - the subclass?
}

class B extends A {
}
```

Is this bad? If so, is this the solution:

```
abstract class A {
  add(InterfaceB);
}

class B extends A implements InterfaceB {
}

interface B {}
```

Comment: These aren't the same.  In the first, `B` inherits from `A`; in the second, it doesn't.

Comment: Also, the answer to this really depends first on the question "why do you need to do this at all?.  i.e. what is the use-case here?

Comment: Ah sry.. Forgot to write "extends A"

Answer (score 0):

It's usually considered better that a super class doesn't know about its sub-classes. This is done to keep the program [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) and easier to maintain as a result.

The solution would really depend on what you are trying to do. Your code looks like it might be a [Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) implementation, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The properties and behaviors of a superclass is common for all the subclass. So Design 2nd is better than 1st.

But it also depends upon what you are trying to do. If your superclass performs some calculation on the dataitems of the subclass and all the subclass want that functionality. go for 2nd solution but if you want this functionality for a specific type of subclass then go 
for solution 1st.